# How to run an Excel VBA from a node.js program?

Tags: node.js, excel, csv, vba

I have a VBA code in Excel doing some formatting. The Excel is getting created by node.js. Is it possible to run that code in Excel by node.js code?

Comment: I don't think node actually uses Excel to compose the document. That said, no, since Excel is not involved at all.

Comment: I am actually creating a CSV using csv-ya module. Post the creation of the csv, the Macro comes into picture.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for something like this is probably going to be to use a module such as [`edge`](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) which allows you to run .NET code (with *can* automate Excel and other applications) from node.